# Selenium Launches Firefox While Silently Ignoring Profile Preference

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, webdriver

There are currently two recommended ways to launch the latest version of Selenium using a specific profile. One is through the `Desired Capabilities` object and the other us by using `Firefox Options`.

**Desired Capabilities**:

```
public static WebDriver launchFirefoxProfileByFFCapabilities()
{
    WebDriver driver = null;
    
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "PATH");
            
    
    ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
    String profileName = "Profile_1";
    FirefoxProfile firefoxProfileByProfilesIni = profile.getProfile(profileName);   
    
    
    DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    dc.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, firefoxProfileByProfilesIni);
    FirefoxOptions opt = new FirefoxOptions();
    opt.merge(dc);

    driver =  new FirefoxDriver(opt);
    
    
    return driver;
}
```

**Firefox Options**:

```
public static WebDriver launchFirefoxProfileByFFOptions()
{
    WebDriver driver = null;
    
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "PATH");
            
    
    ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
    String profileName = "Profile_1";
    FirefoxProfile firefoxProfileByProfilesIni = profile.getProfile(profileName);

    
    FirefoxOptions opt = new FirefoxOptions();
    opt.setProfile(firefoxProfileByProfilesIni);
    
    driver =  new FirefoxDriver(opt);
    
    
    return driver;
}
```

I noticed a few interesting discrepancies between the two approaches and I'm trying to understand what is the reason for these discrepancies and how to prevent them.

**1)** With **Firefox Options** when the specified Profile Name does not exist (as it appears in the `Firefox - Choose User Profile dialog`) throws `WebDriverException: Unexpected value for profile: null`. However with `Desired Capabilities` no such exception is thrown and *Selenium silently ignores the profile preference* (which is not ideal)

**2)** If the Profile Name exists (as it appears in the `Firefox - Choose User Profile dialog`) but the path in `profiles.ini` file is incorrect even **Firefox Options** will launch silently ignore the profile preference and launch `WebDriver` not connected to any profile

What is the cause of these discrepancies? How can they be prevented?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Capabilities and FirefoxProfile/FirefoxOptions handle the profileIni in a different way.

Could you please modify and add the stack-traces so we can further help you?